# I made a script for wall jumping but Invoke() function isn't working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I made a script for wall jump but Invoke() function is not working
the error I get is "Trying to Invoke method:KarakterKontrol.DuvarZiplamasiniBoz couldn't be called."

```
        private void Update()
    {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && IsSliding == true)
        {
            WallJump = true;
            Invoke("DuvarZiplamasiniBoz", WallJumpTime);
        }

        if(DuvarZiplamasi == true)
        {
            karakterRB.velocity = new Vector2(xWallForce * -input, yWallForce);
        }

        void DuvarZiplamasiniBoz()
        {
            WallJump = false;
        }
```

Comment: Does this compile at all?

Comment: Ha, you just tought me something. I never knew you can create local methods within a method.

Comment: Why do want to Invoke() the method DuvarZiplamasiniBoz? You can just call it like so DuvarZiplamasiniBoz(). If you want to pass in the parameter WallJumpTime you have to declare that like so: DuvarZiplamasiniBoz(<type of WallJumpTime> wallJumpTime) { ... If type is DateTime the it would be DuvarZiplamasiniBoz(DateTime wallJumpTime).

Answer (score 0):

Put the void DuvarZiplamasiniBoz outside of the Update method. this is why you cant invoke the method.

do it like this:

```
     private void Update()
    {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && IsSliding == true)
        {
            WallJump = true;
            Invoke("DuvarZiplamasiniBoz", WallJumpTime);
        }

        if(DuvarZiplamasi == true)
        {
            karakterRB.velocity = new Vector2(xWallForce * -input, yWallForce);
        }

      }
    private void DuvarZiplamasiniBoz()
     {
          WallJump = false;
     }
```

or use a coroutine to wait for seconds.